# systemd string formatting for instance parameter

Tags: systemd, systemd-service

I'm trying to set up a `systemd` service that takes a parameter, and uses it in a couple places. I think I'm very close: with my config file name `myservice@.service`, I can run `systemctl start myservice@foo myservice@bar`, and use `%i` in the config to get `foo` and `bar` in the service instances.

The trick is that I need the parameter to be upper case in one section, but lowercase in another.

```
# foo instance
User=myuser-%i   # myuser-foo
ExecStart=my_command /data/%i  # needs to be /data/FOO



# bar instance
User=myuser-%i   # myuser-bar
ExecStart=my_command /data/%i  # needs to be /data/BAR
```

So far the only way I can think to do this is write a wrapper script, and change to `ExecStart=my_wrapper.sh %i` to let the wrapper do the necessary string formatting. That seems clunky though, is this possible directly in the service config?

Answer (score 0):

You could use bash's uppercase parameter syntax: `${v^^}` converts the characters in variable `$v` to uppercase.  So you would like to do something like `v="%i"; cmd /data/${v^^}`. You need to stop systemd from interpreting `${}`, so use `$$` for `$`.

```
ExecStart=bash -c 'v="%i"; exec my_command /data/"$${v^^}"'
```

Comment: Cool, I think this should work. My system doesn't seem to like that as-is though, it wants an absolute path to the executable (so `/bin/bash`)

Comment: Yes, older versions of systemd only take absolute pathnames. For newer ones see [man systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines), and the section headed "Command Lines" for the allowed syntax, and the command `systemd-path search-binaries-default` to show the PATH used for `Exec...=`.